Python: Cannot use CircUp in command prompt due to NameError (Windows)
I'm very new to Python and I am trying to install CircUp. I installed it using pip (following the directions here: https://learn.adafruit.com/keep-your-circuitpython-libraries-on-devices-up-to-date-with-circup/install-circup). But when I try to run a CircUp command in the command prompt, I get the error: NameError: name 'circup' is not defined.
When I finished installing CircUp, the command line output stated that it had been successfully installed. I ran the command circup --version to verify, expecting it to return the version number of my installation. But instead, I got the following result:
>>> circup --version
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'circup' is not defined

Here is my full command log. Note that I added the path 'C:\Users\Name\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python312\Scripts' to PATH after seeing the warnings.
C:\Users\Name>python3 --version
Python 3.12.5

C:\Users\Name>pip3 --version
pip 24.2 from C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_3.12.1520.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.12)

C:\Users\Name>git version
git version 2.37.3.windows.1

C:\Users\Name>python3 -m site --user-base
C:\Users\Name\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages

C:\Users\Name>pip install setuptools
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Collecting setuptools
  Downloading setuptools-72.2.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (6.6 kB)
Downloading setuptools-72.2.0-py3-none-any.whl (2.3 MB)
   ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 2.3/2.3 MB 7.8 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Installing collected packages: setuptools
Successfully installed setuptools-72.2.0

C:\Users\Name>pip install circup
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Collecting circup
  Downloading circup-2.0.4-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (13 kB)
Collecting appdirs (from circup)
  Downloading appdirs-1.4.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (9.0 kB)
Collecting Click (from circup)
  Downloading click-8.1.7-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (3.0 kB)
Collecting findimports (from circup)
  Downloading findimports-2.5.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (6.5 kB)
Collecting requests (from circup)
  Downloading requests-2.32.3-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (4.6 kB)
Collecting semver (from circup)
  Downloading semver-3.0.2-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (5.0 kB)
Collecting toml (from circup)
  Downloading toml-0.10.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (7.1 kB)
Collecting update-checker (from circup)
  Downloading update_checker-0.18.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (2.3 kB)
Collecting colorama (from Click->circup)
  Downloading colorama-0.4.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (17 kB)
Collecting charset-normalizer<4,>=2 (from requests->circup)
  Downloading charset_normalizer-3.3.2-cp312-cp312-win_amd64.whl.metadata (34 kB)
Collecting idna<4,>=2.5 (from requests->circup)
  Downloading idna-3.7-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (9.9 kB)
Collecting urllib3<3,>=1.21.1 (from requests->circup)
  Downloading urllib3-2.2.2-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (6.4 kB)
Collecting certifi>=2017.4.17 (from requests->circup)
  Downloading certifi-2024.7.4-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (2.2 kB)
Downloading circup-2.0.4-py3-none-any.whl (37 kB)
Downloading appdirs-1.4.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl (9.6 kB)
Downloading click-8.1.7-py3-none-any.whl (97 kB)
Downloading findimports-2.5.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (16 kB)
Downloading requests-2.32.3-py3-none-any.whl (64 kB)
Downloading semver-3.0.2-py3-none-any.whl (17 kB)
Downloading toml-0.10.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (16 kB)
Downloading update_checker-0.18.0-py3-none-any.whl (7.0 kB)
Downloading certifi-2024.7.4-py3-none-any.whl (162 kB)
Downloading charset_normalizer-3.3.2-cp312-cp312-win_amd64.whl (100 kB)
Downloading idna-3.7-py3-none-any.whl (66 kB)
Downloading urllib3-2.2.2-py3-none-any.whl (121 kB)
Downloading colorama-0.4.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl (25 kB)
Installing collected packages: appdirs, urllib3, toml, semver, idna, findimports, colorama, charset-normalizer, certifi, requests, Click, update-checker, circup
  WARNING: The script pysemver.exe is installed in 'C:\Users\Name\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python312\Scripts' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
  WARNING: The script findimports.exe is installed in 'C:\Users\Name\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python312\Scripts' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
  WARNING: The script normalizer.exe is installed in 'C:\Users\Name\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python312\Scripts' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
  WARNING: The script circup.exe is installed in 'C:\Users\Name\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python312\Scripts' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
Successfully installed Click-8.1.7 appdirs-1.4.4 certifi-2024.7.4 charset-normalizer-3.3.2 circup-2.0.4 colorama-0.4.6 findimports-2.5.0 idna-3.7 requests-2.32.3 semver-3.0.2 toml-0.10.2 update-checker-0.18.0 urllib3-2.2.2

C:\Users\Name>python
Python 3.12.5 (tags/v3.12.5:ff3bc82, Aug  6 2024, 20:45:27) [MSC v.1940 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> circup --version
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'circup' is not defined


circup --version is a command for your OS command line, not the Python interpreter.

@jasonharper Thank you for replying. As per the installation instructions, I did all of this in my operating system command line (Windows command prompt).

Right, you did everything at the Windows command prompt - until the very end, where you ran python, and then gave the circup --version command from inside Python - where it cannot possibly work.  Notice the different prompt?  >>> instead of C:\Users\Name>?
